# cgi file not visible to apache, html form returns null values

Tags: apache2, perl, cgi

I have a html table that has 2 radio buttons for every row and a save button. I want to store the value of the radio button when saved and preset the value when the page is revisited.This is the html code I have written

```
<form action='table_extract.cgi' method = 'post'>
        <td><input type='radio' name='signoff' value = 'approve'>Approve<br>
        <input type='radio' name='signoff' value='review'>Review</td>
    <td><input type='submit' name='button' value='Save'/></td></form>
```

This is what is in table_extract.cgi

```
#!usr/local/bin/perl
use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);
use strict;
use warnings;
print <<END;
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
END

my $regfile = 'signoff.out';
my $sign;
$sign = param('signoff');

open(REG,">>$regfile") or fail();
print REG "$sign\n";
close(REG);
print "param value :", param('signoff');
print <<END;
<title>Thank you!</title>
<h1>Thank you!</h1>
<p>signoff preference:$sign </p>
END

sub fail {
   print "<title>Error</title>",
   "<p>Error: cannot record your registration!</p>";
  exit; }
```

I'm not able to pass the params from the html form `.cgi` script. I searched online and found out that the Apache server needs visibility to the cgi scripts. I tried to check if the load cgi functions on `httpd.conf` and moved the cgi script to `cgi-bin`. It doesn't work. I still get null values when I try to execute the `.cgi` file.

Comment: Any entries in Apaches error and access log?

Answer (score 0):

I would start from checking permissions if this script is executable:

```
chmod +x table_extract.cgi
```

Additionally please check log files in

```
/var/log/http/*
```

Check if your script runs without syntax error:

```
perl -c table_extract.cgi
```

If your HTML page is not located under cgi-bin directory then please consider modifying form action parameter to:

```
<form action='/cgi-bin/table_extract.cgi' method = 'post'>
```

Comment: `chmod +x` does not return anything on the command line. I was not able to find the log files. I am not the root user. The script runs without any syntax errors. For the html page to be accessible via browser, I need to put the html page in a certain folder in unix which is not inside the `Apache`. i tried placing the `cgi` script under `cgi-bin` and also with the html page. There is no change.

Comment: Well I think you will have to send more details about your server. Do you have access to apache configuration? What server is it? Maybe this is a question to your server's administrators if perl mod is enabled? chmod +x is not returning anything. It adds executable flag to your file.